# Vowpal wabbit with Java / JNI using the linux precompiled binaries

Tags: java-native-interface, vowpalwabbit

I was testing the vowpal_wabbit for the first time and basically, I'm going to execute it on a Docker container, so I've downloaded a precompiled version as suggested here [official download page](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Download) and apparently it worked as expected inside my container.
[image]

It turns out that I was intending to use Java and invoke VW-Wabbit (and the option, although not easy, was to use JNI - and later check a wrapper for it created by the Indeed guys). However, if I'm using a precompiled when I try to load the native library, it won't find it (once I didn't do any compile/make/whatever), right?

Given that:

```
static {
        System.loadLibrary("vw_jni");
    }
```

I suppose the Java is trying to reach in my Linux: "vw_jni" -> "vw_jni.so" and as I didn't compile, I don't have it.

Thanks in advance,
Am I missing any point here?

Comment: The statically linked pre-compiled binaries are the C command line executables only.  If you need the Java API, you need to set JAVA_HOME correctly for your env, and `make java`.  This should build the jni wrapper in `java/target/libvw_jni.so`

Comment: @arielf thanks for your comment. I do have a correct JAVA_HOME:
`[root@09ea09b3f98f vowpal_wabbit]# echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_74`
 And what I have apart from this is the single binary file aforementioned:  
`-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 6117312 Feb  5 16:58 vw-8.20170920`

as far as I understood to execute `make java` I should have the structure of the github vowpal-wabbit project with the folder java and the Makefile inside. Isn't it?

Comment: I see (on the mailing list) you've managed to build the JNI from source.  The key is to avoid `autogen.sh` (it is provided only as a last-resort. It overwrites the`Makefile`s) and simply use `make java` with the original `Makefile`s that come with the source.  If you already overwrote the `Makefile`s, you can get the originals back easily using `git checkout Makefile */Makefile` - writing this to possibly help others in the future.

Comment: Thanks, @arielf - if you want to copy and paste the comment into the "answer" field, I'll be glad to mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the use of `autogen.sh`.

`autogen.sh` is provided only as a last-resort for possibly unfamiliar/unsupported environments where the provided `Makefile` (and child directory `*/Makefile`s) may not work.

Among other things,`autogen.sh` calls GNU `automake` which overwrites the `Makefile`s (based on probing the environment).

To generate the JNI, you need to run `make java` with the *original* Makefiles that come with the source.

If you already overwrote the Makefiles, no worries! You can easily restore the originals back by typing:

```
git checkout Makefile */Makefile

# Now you can
make java
```

resulting in a good vw java wrapper: `java/target/libvw_jni.so`